# Access Method in TabBarController from other class

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitabbar, navigationbar

i spend the last hours to fix this problem but nothing did helped. My LocationHelper Delegate looks like this:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            print("not terminated")
            break
        case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
            NavigationBarController().checkLocationBasedElements(result: 1)

            print("auth okay")
            break
        case .restricted, .denied:
            NavigationBarController().checkLocationBasedElements(result: 2)
            print("auth denied")
            break
        }
    }
```

When the Authorization Status changes, i can see the print-outputs correctly on the console. My NavigationBarController.checkLocationBasedElements looks like this:

```
func checkLocationBasedElements(result: Int) -> Void{
        if(result == 2){
            print("checklocation: 2")
            tabBar.items?[1].isEnabled = false
            tabBar.items?[2].isEnabled = false
        }
        if(result == 1){
            //auth ok
            print("checklocation: 1")
            tabBar.items?[1].isEnabled = true
            tabBar.items?[2].isEnabled = true
        }

    }
```

When the User changes the auth-status to .authorizedWhenInUse the console gives this output:

```
checklocation: 1
auth okay
```

So it can be said that the methods get called correctly. But the tabBar do not change the isEnabled to true or false. I tried much things like putting the logic into the NavigationBarControllers' viewDidLoad or check the permission-status every time the app gets opened but this is not a very elegant solution I think so that i implemented the delegate. Do I have to instanciate the NavigationBarController otherwise like I have done it or what would you recommend?

Thanks in advance!
Edit:
NavigationBarController:

```
import UIKit

class NavigationBarController: UITabBarController {

    //let locationHelper = LocationHelper()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        let iconSize = CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
        let iconUnselected = UIColor.white
        let iconSelected = UIColor.gray

        //Start
        tabBar.items?[0].title = "Start"
        tabBar.items?[0].setFAIcon(icon: .FAHome, size: iconSize, textColor: iconUnselected, backgroundColor: .clear, selectedTextColor: iconSelected, selectedBackgroundColor: .clear)

        //Live
        tabBar.items?[1].title = "Live"
        tabBar.items?[1].setFAIcon(icon: .FATachometer, size: iconSize, textColor: iconUnselected, backgroundColor: .clear, selectedTextColor: iconSelected, selectedBackgroundColor: .clear)

        //Messen
        tabBar.items?[2].title = "Messen"
        tabBar.items?[2].setFAIcon(icon: .FAClockO, size: iconSize, textColor: iconUnselected, backgroundColor: .clear, selectedTextColor: iconSelected, selectedBackgroundColor: .clear)

        //Ergebnisse
        tabBar.items?[3].title = "Ergebnisse"
        tabBar.items?[3].setFAIcon(icon: .FAWindowRestore, size: iconSize, textColor: iconUnselected, backgroundColor: .clear, selectedTextColor: iconSelected, selectedBackgroundColor: .clear)



        //Check GPS Permission
        //self.checkLocationBasedElements(result: LocationHelper.shared.checkStatus())


    }
    func checkLocationBasedElements(result: Int) -> Void{
        //look above

    }
```

Comment: Do you have a previously existing `NavigationBarController` somewhere?  The one you're creating here isn't presented on the screen.

Comment: Could please show how you initialized tabBar? I guess you are creating an instance of tabBar rather accessing the actual tabBar.

Comment: edited @PhillipMills

Comment: Your edit doesn't actually address the questions.

Comment: @PhillipMills Ouh, sorry! Yes, my TabBar is controlled by the NavigationBarController. The connection was made in the Story Board. i do not use or declare tabBar before. i just write `tabBar. (...)` and it works in the viewDidLoad(). So i thought that it works in an other method of the class too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your current design, the quickest solution would be:

1. Your `LocationHelper` should declare an instance of `NavigationBarController`

   ```
   class LocationHelper {
       //...
       weak var myTabBarController: NavigationBarController?
       //...
   }
   ```
2. `myTabBarController` should be set once from `NavigationBarController`:

   ```
   class NavigationBarController: UITabBarController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

           LocationHelper.shared.myTabBarController = self

           //...
       }

   }
   ```
3. Your `locationManager(_ manager:didChangeAuthorization:)` should call

   ```
   myTabBarController?.checkLocationBasedElements(result:)
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   NavigationBarController().checkLocationBasedElements(result:)
   ```

   i.e.

   ```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
       switch status {
       case .notDetermined:
           print("not terminated")
       case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
           myTabBarController?.checkLocationBasedElements(result: 1)

           print("auth okay")
       case .restricted, .denied:
           myTabBarController?.checkLocationBasedElements(result: 2)
           print("auth denied")
       }
   }
   ```

Basically when you do `NavigationBarController().checkLocationBasedElements(result:)` you are running `checkLocationBasedElements(result:)` on a new instance of `NavigationBarController` which is not the same as the one that's containing the tabs you see.

Comment: Top, worked! I think i had a wrong thinking about the whole problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @wannabe_informatiker my pleasure. just one thing, make that `var myTabBarController: NavigationBarController?` a weak property. Just... for more um... robustness [:answer updated:]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in this line

```
  NavigationBarController().checkLocationBasedElements(result: 1)
```

you create another instance  (`NavigationBarController()`)  other than the presented one , so try to make it a shared singleton , or use notification center / delegate to inform enabling/disabling tabBars

Comment: hi! When i put a `static var shared = NavigationBarController()` under the `Class NavigationBarController (...)`, and call the method via `NavigationBarController.shared.checkLocationBasedElements(result:1)` I got the error that the type navigationbarcontroller has no member 'shared'. But this is the same way i implemented the shared instance at my Other class and it works...

Comment: see here right way to declare a singletion https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift/ ,,,, for know you can use notificationCenter try to add observers in NavigationBarController class viewDidLoad , and post in didChangeAuthorization